# Node js & socket io cookie value does not exists

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, cookies, socket.io

I am trying to set a cookie when my users log into my system i do this after the password and user name has been auth.

```
       setcookie('lb_login_id', $_SESSION['User']['id']);
```

Now it is after this point my user then connects to the socket:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://mydomain.local' + ':' + 3000);
```

Then when the user is connected i am printing out cookie data:

```
    io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    console.log(socket.request.headers.cookie);

});
```

However the `lb_login_id` value is not in the cookie:

```
io=fP13ZJ4Lgk2UL2QmAAAA; PHPSESSID=257r236nn3a1ru0b8lf2ocuvh4; XDEBUG_SESSION=XDEBUG_ECLIPSE
```

Can anyone tell me what might be wrong?

**Update**

After debugging i can see that after i redirect to an internal page the cookie is also gone from my `$_COOKIE array`?

Comment: Are you using `session_start()` before you try to set a cookie in PHP?

Comment: Yes. And the session variables are saved correctly in my $_SESSION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer at another question:

[PHP not saving cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073304/cookie-not-saving)

Apprently you have to specify the domain